# SVN Authentication with LDAP and Active Directory

Tags: svn, active-directory, ldap

I am having a few problems getting SVN authentication to work with LDAP / Active Directory. My SVN installation works fine, but after enabling LDAP in my apache vhost, I just can't get my users to authenticate.

I can use a selection of LDAP browsers to successfully connect to Active Directory, but just can't seem to get this to work.

- SVN is setup in /var/local/svn
- Server is svn.domain.local
- For testing, my repository is /var/local/svn/test

My vhost file is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin alex@domain.com
        ServerAlias svn.domain.local
        ServerName svn.domain.local
        DocumentRoot /var/www/svn/

        <Location /test>
                DAV svn
                #SVNListParentPath On
                SVNPath /var/local/svn/test
                AuthzSVNAccessFile /var/local/svn/svnaccess
                AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "SVN Server"
                AuthBasicProvider ldap
                AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=adminuser,OU=SBSAdmin Users,OU=Users,OU=MyBusiness,DC=domain,DC=local"
                AuthLDAPBindPassword "admin password"
                AuthLDAPURL "ldap://192.168.1.6:389/OU=SBSUsers,OU=Users,OU=MyBusiness,DC=domain,DC=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
                Require valid-user
        </Location>

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/svn/access.log combined
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/svn/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

In my error.log, I don't seem to get any bind errors (should I be looking elsewhere?), but just the following:

```
[Thu Jun 21 09:51:38 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.142] user alex: authentication failure for "/test/": Password Mismatch, referer: http://svn.domain.local/test/
```

At the end of "AuthLDAPURL", I have seen people using TLS and NONE but neither seem to help in my case.

I have the ldap modules loaded and have checked as much as I know, so any help would be most welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `REFERRALS off` in the server `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf` and try again.

And try adding "NONE" to the URL line:

```
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://192.168.1.6:389/OU=SBSUsers,OU=Users,OU=MyBusiness,DC=domain,DC=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)" NONE
```

Try ldapsearch. Do an `.ldaprc` in your home directory with this:

```
HOST 192.168.1.6
BASE DC=domain,DC=local
BINDDN CN=adminuser,OU=SBSAdmin Users,OU=Users,OU=MyBusiness,DC=domain,DC=local
```

Use it:

```
ldapsearch -D "CN=adminuser,OU=SBSAdmin Users,OU=Users,OU=MyBusiness,DC=domain,DC=local" -W sAMAccountName=user
```

It will ask for the BindDN password.

Comment: Afraid that doesn't seem to work. I get the same "authentication failure" messages in /var/log/apache2/svn/error.log - I'm certain that my password is correct, and my username is "alexh" and not "alexh@domain.local". Is there a way to get a more verbose output?

Comment: Would I be able to use this ldapsearch tool to confirm that I can connect? I've struggled to understand what parameters to pass to it.

Comment: I've updated the solution with information about ldapsearch.

Comment: Thanks Diego. I created the .ldaprc file in /home/user and then ran the ldapsearch. It gave me: ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1). I also tried this command and it seemed to work: ldapsearch -x -b "dc=domain,dc=local" -D "domain\adminuser" -h 192.168.1.6 -p 389 -W - does that tell you anything?

Comment: OK, I made changes to my /etc/ldap/ldap.conf file and ran ldapsearch -x and it gave a bind error (LDAPv3) - error was "In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v1db1"

Comment: Are you sure the binding credentials are OK? Active Directory is a little stubborn and wants the full BINDDN token.

Comment: Edit: Looks like that test of yours works where I specify ldapsearch -D. So, the next step would be to get that working as part of SVN in the vhosts file. I'll test again

Comment: I enabled debug logging and this is the apache error.log: [Thu Jun 21 15:52:09 2012] [debug] mod_authnz_ldap.c(403): [client 192.168.1.142] [7066] auth_ldap authenticate: using URL ldap://192.168.1.6:389/OU=Users,OU=MyBusiness,DC=domain,DC=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)
[Thu Jun 21 15:52:09 2012] [info] [client 192.168.1.142] [7066] auth_ldap authenticate: user alexh authentication failed; URI /test/ [LDAP: ldap_simple_bind_s() failed][Invalid credentials]
[Thu Jun 21 15:52:09 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.142] user alexh: authentication failure for "/test/": Password Mismatch

Comment: Does it matter that the bind user, and the user that needs to login are in different OUs? My structure is DC->Users then I have SBSAdmin Users SBSUsers as 2 different OUs within the Users OU. This is so frustrating as I bet it's something really simple!

Comment: Recheck the binding credentials and use the full BindDN. In the AuthLDAPURL use _only_ the domain: AuthLDAPURL "ldap://192.168.1.6:389/DC=domain,DC=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)" NONE

Comment: I'm afraid is still not letting me in. I've tried several different attempts as the BindDN (username, username@domain.local, CN=username....) but none seem to work. The error log still seems to give me Invalid Credentials / Password Mismatch. Is this just an authentication problem (I thought if the BindDN was wrong - I would get a bind error and not a user login error) - or perhaps something else?

Comment: Can anyone help further please?

Answer (score 2):

Diego gets the points as it finally led me to get it working. It may have been a case of changing the order of the params in my virtualhost, but this is what worked for me. I also copied the admin user DN directly from an LDAP GUI tool to ensure I had the correct bind details:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
        ServerAlias svn.domain.local
        ServerName svn.domain.local
        DocumentRoot /var/www/svn/

        <Location />
                DAV svn
                SVNParentPath /var/local/svn/
                SVNListParentPath On
                AuthBasicProvider ldap
                AuthType Basic
                AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
                AuthName "SVN Server"
                AuthLDAPURL "ldap://192.168.1.6:389/DC=domain,DC=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)" NONE
                AUTHLDAPBindDN "CN=admin,OU=Admin Users,OU=Users,OU=MyBusiness,DC=domain,DC=local"
                AuthLDAPBindPassword ######
                require valid-user
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope that helps someone else out!

Answer (score 1):

It may not directly answer your question, but did you consider to use [Subversion Edge](http://www.collab.net/products/subversion/capabilities)? It is free to use (AGPLv3 license).

As you can see in this [screenshot](http://www.collab.net/sites/all/themes/collabnet/_media/screenshots/subversionedge/capabilities/images/ldap.jpg) it is quite simple to setup LDAP integration. You can even install the SSPI module though this requires some manual work.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I'm open to alternatives, and I will give Subversion Edge a go. I'd still like to find an answer to my specific problem as well, as I have seen others with similar problems. Thanks again