# ldap not working with svn

Tags: ldap, httpd, svn

Authentication fails with password mismatch error whilst trying to login to svn repo. Following is the config for 10-subversion.conf

Tried everything but nothing seemed to worked including changing the ports. ldapsearch to the the ldap user works fine and returns the value. checked firewall is not blocking the port 389. checked selinux bits as well.

Tried adding the tha authz file in the config to provide specific users from AD access to repos, still doesnt work:

AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/httpd/conf/access.conf

access.conf file has following config:

[repo:/]
user1 = rw

10-subversion.conf has following conf:

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so
LoadModule dontdothat_module  modules/mod_dontdothat.so
LoadModule ldap_module        modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so

<Location /svn>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /mnt/repositories
   AuthBasicProvider ldap
   AuthType basic
   AuthName "LDAP Authentication"
   AuthLDAPURL "ldap://192.0.0.1:389/DC=companyname,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)" 
   AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=svn ldap,CN=Users,DC=companyname,DC=com"
   AuthLDAPBindPassword "pwd"
   Require valid-user
</Location>
```

this is the error log:

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::250:56ff:febe:ad73%ens192. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sat Feb 17 11:23:55.968391 2024] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1847930:tid 1847930] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sat Feb 17 11:23:55.971999 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1847930:tid 1847930] AH00489: Apache/2.4.57 (Rocky Linux) OpenSSL/3.0.7 SVN/1.14.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Feb 17 11:23:55.972059 2024] [core:notice] [pid 1847930:tid 1847930] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sat Feb 17 11:27:43.893361 2024] [auth_basic:error] [pid 1847939:tid 1848143] [client 10.0.98.1:55569] AH01617: user admin: authentication failure for "/svn/repo/": Password Mismatch
```

Comment: What does your logs show?

Comment: logs show the password mismatch error whilst authenticating:

Comment: perhaps this can help https://serverfault.com/questions/431290/svn-authentication-with-ldap-and-active-directory